# When handling a SIP request, how do I run a long-run running function before sending a response?

Tags: c, asterisk, pjsip

I am writing an Asterisk module. When a certain SIP request is received, I want to wait until a certain condition is triggered, and only after it finish (max 5 seconds), should Asterisk's core functions be allowed to process this request further.

I tried creating a `pj_thread_t` where my long-running task runs, and there is a loop that runs multiple times with a delay (`pj_thread_sleep`) until the expected condition is satisfied. However, this blocks all SIP message handling in Asterisk and not just the one I'm handling.

Is using a `pj_thread_t` not the right approach?

**Update**: I missed out a detail in my original post. I was waiting for a semaphor in the main thread. The new thread wasn't actually blocking when calling `pj_thread_sleep`. However, the problem still remains. I need to return `PJ_FALSE` from the main thread after the new thread finishes executing, so that the rest of the modules can continue processing the request after I'm done with it.

Comment: I assume the problem is not the thread, but rather the sleeping. See if there's some error code you can return from your module that means "i'll get back to you" or "ask me again later"

Comment: If I return from the module, then Asterisk will continue processing the request, which is not the behavior I need. Also, because I'm handling an INVITE request, if I return an error code then the call will fail.

Comment: right so you should see if there's something you can return that says "don't continue processing until I tell you". Some module APIs have that sort of thing.

Comment: would the initiator time out after 5 seconds? You might also consider connecting them to something that says "your call is important to us. please hold...."

Comment: I made a mistake. Calling pj_thread_sleep() from the new thread does not block. In the main thread, I was waiting for a semaphor which was what was causing the block.  However I'm still uncertain about how to wait in the main thread before I return from it. I will update the question.

Comment: I am looking at the PJSIP documentation and I don't see anything about processing incoming requests. How does your module know when an INVITE request is received?

Comment: Is it [this request handler `on_rx_request`](https://docs.pjsip.org/en/latest/api/generated/pjsip/group/group__PJSIP__MOD.html)? Great, then say so. So what happens if you return true to say you handled the request?

Comment: The request handler receives a `pjsip_rx_data` which contains parsed method and you can check if the id is equal to `PJSIP_INVITE_METHOD`.  You can see this function (https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/18.16/res/res_pjsip_logger.c#L338-L368) as an example of how to handle incoming requests. In this function, `rdata->msg_info.msg->line.req.method.id` will be equal to `PJSIP_INVITE_METHOD` when it's an INVITE request.

Comment: If I return `PJ_TRUE` that would mean  my module has handled the request. If I return `PJ_FALSE` then it tells Asterisk to continue processing. I don't want to disrupt the normal flow, so I just want to return `PJ_FALSE` but only after the new thread is completed.

Comment: sounds like it might be impossible in this library, but you know, I don't really know this library so I won't commit to that. You're trying to block all processing without blocking all processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not(I will repeat, **SHOULD NOT**) do any threaded logic like that in the core processing thread. It will result in very hard-catching issues with core and logic.
Your RTP processing thread should be as light as possible.

The best option is to do it outside asterisk at all, in external logic. Using AMI, ARI or FastAGI.

If you still want do some backgroundround checks, see the source code of Background or Read applications.
Another waiting and quite complex example is AMD app.
Anyway, it should be done in application, not RTP processing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Marking this as the correct answer. I've re-implemented this as a session supplement so I can use `ast_safe_sleep` on the specific channel, rather than doing anything in the main processing thread. Now the issue is resolved.